# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

```
line1 = (n1,'-',n2,'-',n3,'-',n4,'-',n5,'powerball =',pb,"----> Random       Numbers",'\n')
line2 = (l1,'-',l2,'-',l3,'-',l4,'-',l5,'powerball =',lpb,"----> Low Numbers",'\n')
line3 = (m1,'-',m2,'-',m3,'-',m4,'-',m5,'powerball =',mpb,"----> Medium Numbers",'\n')
line4 = (h1,'-',h2,'-',h3,'-',h4,'-',h5,'powerball =',hpb,"----> Hi Numbers",'\n')
line5 = (n1,'-',l2,'-',m3,'-',h4,'-',n5,'powerball =',lpb,"----> Mixed       Numbers",'\n')


file1 = (line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5)

file_name = "file_name"
today1 = open(file_name , "r+")
file_name = file1
file_name.write();
```

this the code and I get this error on write
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'
I've read everything I can find 
still don't know what I'm doing wrong
I'm real new at Python
thanks

Comment: Nope; This gives "NameError: name 'file1' is not defined".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: more of the code line1 = (n1,'-',n2,'-',n3,'-',n4,'-',n5,'powerball =',pb,"----> Random Numbers",'\n')
line2 = (l1,'-',l2,'-',l3,'-',l4,'-',l5,'powerball =',lpb,"----> Low Numbers",'\n')
line3 = (m1,'-',m2,'-',m3,'-',m4,'-',m5,'powerball =',mpb,"----> Medium Numbers",'\n')
line4 = (h1,'-',h2,'-',h3,'-',h4,'-',h5,'powerball =',hpb,"----> Hi Numbers",'\n')
line5 = (n1,'-',l2,'-',m3,'-',h4,'-',n5,'powerball =',lpb,"----> Mixed Numbers",'\n')
file1 = (line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5)

file_name = "file_name"
today1 = open(file_name , "r+")
file_name = file1
file_name.write();

Comment: more of the code

Comment: Edit that code into the original question, not in a comment.  Again, please follow the posting guidelines.  I know there are a lot of them.

Comment: This is still not an MCVE.  There are about a dozen undefined symbols in this.  Please replace those top few lines with a single, readable assignment to `file1`.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind ... I see the problem:

```
file_name = "file_name"
today1 = open(file_name , "r+")
# At this point, you've opened the file "file_name"

file_name = file1
# Here, the variable file_name now contains that monster string
#   you put together.
# You have utterly lost the handle to your open file.

file_name.write();
# You have just tried to write output to that monster string.
# "write" is a file command, not a string operation.
```

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
file_name = "file_name"
today1 = open(file_name , "r+")
file_name.write(file1);
```

This will (attempt to) write the value of that monster string to the output file.  I'm worried about the file mode: "read extend".  What did you plan to read from the file?  What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: i was trying to write a file to send to printer guess my string is too long

Comment: No, read my comments: you tried to call `write`, a file method, using a string.  You have to call `write` on a file, giving the data (your string) as the argument).